# Topological entropy and pseudo-Anosov dilatation for punctured surface

Tags: geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, mapping-class-groups

Let $S_{g,n}$ be a closed surface of genus $g$ with $n$ punctures. Assume $2-2g-n<0$. Let $f$ be a pseudo-Anosov mapping class with dilatation $\lambda_f$. In the introduction (1st page) of the paper ["Bounds on least dilatations"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-113-02/S0002-9939-1991-1068128-8/S0002-9939-1991-1068128-8.pdf), Penner stated two results.

1) $\log(\lambda_f)$ is the Teichmuller length of the Teichmuller geodesic in the Moduli space.

2) $\log(\lambda_f)$ is the minimum of the topological entropy of the elements in the mapping class of $f$.

I know the proof of both of the results for $n=0$.

For the first result author has given the reference of "The real-analytic theory of Teichmüller space" by W. Abikoff.

For the second the reference is "Travaux de Thurston sur les surfaces" by FLP.

The proof 2) in FLP requires $n=0$. On the other hand I don't have the access to Abikoff's result.

Therefore it would be extremely helpful if anybody can explain whether the statements of 1) and 2) are true or not for $n\neq 0$. If they are true, how should one go from $n=0$ to $n\neq 0$.

Any reference, suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.